# How to get last name based on condition in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I have a list of authors' name with irregular format as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'author':['fox district judge', 'louise w flanagan united states district judge', 'amy berman jackson united states district judge', 'rhesa hawkins barksdale, circuit judge','kanne, circuit judge'])
```

When parsing out last name, I used `df['Last_Name'] = df['author'].apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[0].split(' ')[-1])` However, this line of code only worked on the last two author name. How do I extract last name such as `fox` and `flanagan` from the first two rows?

Comment: You need to clean your data and make it uniform. You can do it manually or by multiple replaces. For example, sometimes there is a comma, sometimes there is not. Sometimes it says United states, sometimes it does not. These need to all be normailzed in which ever way you want, then you can use code to pull last names out.

Comment: In this case, would it be a good idea to add "," in front of "district judge" "united states" etc so the code can pick up the last name?

Comment: In my opinion, I would strip united states from every row, and make sure there is always comma before district/circuit judge so then you will know that the last name will always be the word before the comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the last comment, if you want things to be automated and can't "clean" the data without just manually editing it, I would suggest removing everything but the names from the strings (i.e remove the words district, circuit, judge, united, states), as well as any commas. This way all you have left is the names and even if only the last name is left, you know that the last name will always be in the -1 index:

```
last_names = []
to_delete = ['united', 'states', 'district', 'circuit', 'judge']

strings = list(df['author'])
for author_string in strings:
    author_string = author_string.replace(',', "") # remove any commas
    lst = author_string.split(' ')
    temp = lst.copy() # create copy of lst so we can actually remove words
    for word in lst:
        if word in to_delete:
            temp.remove(word)
    last_names.append(temp[-1]) # since only names are left, last name is always the last index

df['Last_Name'] = last_names
```

While it isn't as pretty as the initial method, this seemed to work when I tried it